# How do I read file text which have many lines and save it into Class?

Tags: c#

I have a text file like that:

```
0 06 1.2.3.4 A B
0 09 1.2.3.4 B A
0 19 1.2.3.4 C B
0 25 1.2.3.4 E C
1 15 1.2.3.4 A -
1 26 1.2.3.4 F C
1 30 1.2.3.4 B A
1 36 1.2.3.4 D B
```

First columne is Minute, Second is Second, Third is IP, fourth is URL and final is Refer..
I have a class to save:

```
class LogEntry
{
    private int minute;
    private int second;     
    private string ip;    
    private string url;
    public string Url    
    private string refer;    
}
```

I have to read line by line, remove white space and save it to Class LogEntry
How can Ido that?
:(
            string path = ofd.FileName;
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

```
       // string alltext = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] a = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

        string b = "";
        LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
        string c = String.Empty;
        while ((c = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (string s in a)
            {
                if (s.Trim() != "")
                {


                    entry.Minute = Convert.ToInt32(b);
                    entry.Second = Convert.ToInt32(b);
                    entry.Ip = b;
                    entry.Url = b;
                    entry.Refer = b;

                    b += s + "\n";

                     list.Add(entry);
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

}

Comment: Well which language are you using - C# or Java? What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: I using C#..I wrote like that

Comment: What do you mean by "I wrote like that"? And why did you add the Java tag if you're using C#? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and improve your question.

Comment: @user3478511, you just edited your question to make it much worse.  I advise against that.

Comment: sorry I clicked enter while i had not finished..Please check link below, it my code http://postimg.org/image/ljtks0jl9/

Comment: I wish I can add Image :(

Comment: Paste the code directly, don't post an image. I removed Java tag anyway.

Comment: This isn't a write-my-code-for-me site. If you could provide what you have tried and what didn't work I'm sure many people will be willing to help you, but no one wants to just be presented with your work/school problem and be expected to provide a full solution.

Comment: I posted my code. I tried to remove white space line by line and add into class, but it not work

Answer (score 1):

First use *auto-implemented* properties instaed of fields.

```
class LogEntry
{
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }   
}
```

Then use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with `LINQ` and populate your list:

```
 var logEntries = File.ReadLines("path")
            .Select(x => x.Split())
            .Select(x => new LogEntry
            {
                Minute = int.Parse(x[0]),
                Second = int.Parse(x[1]),
                IP = x[2],
                Url = x[3],
                Reference = x[4]
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: tks so much, and how can i remove white space line by line. I tried but it not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have a textfile that has the following inside it:

`0 06 1.2.3.4 A B
0 09 1.2.3.4 B A
0 19 1.2.3.4 C B
0 25 1.2.3.4 E C
1 15 1.2.3.4 A -
1 26 1.2.3.4 F C
1 30 1.2.3.4 B A
1 36 1.2.3.4 D B`

What you'll need is a class that holds the variables which you wanted to be read line by line (Minute, Second, IP, URL, Refer). These variables must also have get and set accessors or most commonly known as properties, which is essential in saving from a textfile to a class. From here you can now create a separate code that will access the variables and save whatever they contain in your `class LogEntry`. See, the variables in your class doesn't have properties which is not advisable when storing in a class.